# Архитектура демона

Tags: python, демон, php

**Задача:** Есть порядка 10тка скриптов, которые запускаются через каждые N секунд(часов, дней) выполняют действия и записывают результат в БД.
Нужно сделать этот процесс бесперебойным + веб интерфейс.

**Идеи:** В БД создать таблицу info, в которой содержится: ID, path(путь к скрипту), время последнего запуска, период запуска, статус (включен, выключен).
При запуске каждого из 10ти скриптов проверять запущен ли текущий процесс, если да, то убиваю вновь запущенный и оставляю старый + обновляю время(без бесконечного цикла). 
Также будет демон, который следит и вызывает скрипты в нужный момент времени.

Скрипты на php

Демон предполагается написать на python без cron

Целесообразна ли такая реализация или есть более рациональный подход?

Comment: > Также будет демон, который следит и вызывает скрипты в нужный момент времени.

Зачем тогда еще какие-то проверки? Зачем вообще демон, если с задачей справляется крон?

Comment: возможности использовать крон нету.

Comment: Странная идея --

    ... проверять запущен ли текущий процесс, если да, то убиваю вновь запущенный и оставляю старый ...

возможно я чего-то не понял, но кажется более логичным сначала проверить и если уже запущен, то новый не запускать. 

Естественно, запись об этом в лог сделать, если требуется по логике обработки какое-то время модифицировать и т.п.

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать для скриптов python программу supervisor. В pip она есть

Comment: и не только для python, и supervisord есть в виде пакетов.

Comment: @logicall, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: @Expert ♦♦, буду стараться.. Просто на тот момент писал с телефона в дороге..